# Mackey functor structure on equivariant homotopy groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, representation-theory, homotopy-theory

I have read that the equivariant stable homotopy groups $\pi_n^{-}(X)=\pi_n(X^{-}) $ of a $G$-space or $G$-spectrum $X$ have a Mackey functor structure.

Can somebody please explain how the covariant structure is contructed, i.e. if $H \subseteq K$ are subgroups of $G$, how does one get a map

$$   \pi_n^H(X) \rightarrow \pi_n^K(H) \ \ \ \  ?$$

Thank you.

Comment: For finite groups, the construction of the transfer is explained in the notes by Stefan Schwede: http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/~schwede/equivariant.pdf, p. 30 ff.