# The Mackey functor $\underline{\pi}_n(X)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, equivariant-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group and $X$ a pointed $G$-space.
The assignment $G/H\to \pi_n(X^H)$ should define a Mackey functor. I am trying to figure out what the transfers and restrictions are.

If $H\subset K$, then $X^K\subset X^H$ which induces a map $\pi_n(X^K)\to\pi_n(X^H)$ that I would tentatively called the restriction $Res_H^K$ (thanks for pointing out the mistake). Similarly, left multiplication induces a map $\pi_n(X^H)\to \pi_n(X^{gHg^{-1}})$, that I would call $C_g$.

Unfortunately, I am not sure that these are the right definitions. There is a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339954/mackey-functor-structure-on-equivariant-homotopy-groups) for $G$-spectra and the construction for those maps seems pretty elaborate and requires of the ''Wirthmüller isomorphism''. I was hoping my natural definitions are correct (please tell me if they are not) and you can explain how $Tr_H^K:\pi_n(X^H)\to\pi_n(X^K)$ is defined or provide a reference with a detailed exposition.

Comment: short note: you should assume that $\pi_1(X^H)$ is abelian for all $H$ in order to make sense of this. also your transfer is usually called restriction, since we think of a $G$-space as a functor $\mathcal{O}_G^{op} \to \mathrm{Spaces}$. For spectra, you expect a transfer because there is an algebraic one on representations of a finite group $G$. In fact if you check the Guillou-May theorem, one can essentially think of genuine $G$-spectra as "mackey functors of spectra" (plus some coherence either $\infty$-categorically a la barwick or in terms of spectral enrichment.)

Comment: However, there is always a way to turn a coefficient system of abelian groups into a mackey functor but it is done via kan-extension basically, so it is algebraically formal and notably not coming from a "geometric" place (see lemma 3.2 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.12192.pdf).) as a test try to find a map from $\pi_1(X^H) \to \pi_1(X^K)$ by pushing forward loops.  Hope that this helps!

Comment: @AndresMejia thanks for the comments! I'll try to come up with some homomorphisms in the way you say. You've seemed to consider the particular case $n=1$ although the same should work for all positive integers, right? (good point the assumption about $\pi_1$; obvious but easy to forget). You're also completely right about the transfer/restriction as well. I've inadvertently swapped them. Thanks!

Comment: What you call the transfer is the restriction map. The transfer goes in the other direction. It is a stable phenomenon, that is one needs to pass to suspension $G$-spectra to define it (and then one definition is as in the linked answer).

Comment: @VincentBoelens Thanks, I've already corrected the mistake. Isn't it possible to do it in a more naive way?? The other maps are straightforward and don't required of heavy machinery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transfer is a stable phenomenon and cannot exist at the space level. To see why, let $G$ be the cyclic group of order $2$ with generator $c$ and let $X=S^1\wedge EG_+$, where $G$ acts trivially on $S^1$. Then $G$ acts trivially on $\pi_1(X)\cong \pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$.

If the homotopy groups were to have the structure of a Mackey functor, then the double coset formula would say that $\mathrm{Res}\circ \mathrm{Tr}=1+c$, which is multiplication by $2$ on $\pi_1(X)$, since $G$ acts trivially on $\pi_1(X)$. But $X^G$ is a point, hence $\pi_1(X^G)$ is trivial and we arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: As I don't want to consider spectra, I will have to replace the homotopy groups by _stable_ homotopy groups. I still can't think of an expression for the transfer, but I will ask that in another question.

Comment: @Dog_69 I am afraid you cannot get around using $G$-spectra, since it is not true that $\pi_\ast^H(\Sigma^\infty_G X)$ is isomorphic to the stable homotopy group of $X^H$. This is rather confusing of course and has to do with the fact that all $G$-spaces are fibrant, but not all $G$-spectra are.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @VincentBoelens. I was checking [these notes](https://www3.nd.edu/~gszekely/rtg/GTS/www3.nd.edu/_jquigle2/GSTS%20SP17/SP17Week5.pdf) about Mackey functors. It seems I will have to change my definition according to Example 2.3 there: the assignment $G/H\mapsto [S^n\wedge(G/H)_+X]$ is a Mackey functor, but I guess as we are now in the stable case it's not longer true that $[S^n\wedge(G/H)_+X]\cong [S^n,X^H]$, as you were saying, right?

Comment: @Dog_69 Yes, this is only true after replacing $X$ by an $\Omega$-$G$-spectrum (aka deriving the fixed point functor), but a suspension $G$-spectrum is almost never an $\Omega$-$G$-spectrum.