# Transfer map for the Mackey functor $\underline{\pi}_n^H$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory, equivariant-topology

Let $G$ be a finite group ad let $X$ be a $G$-space.
Consider the following Mackey functor, that I will denote by $\underline{\pi}_n$: $G/H\mapsto \pi_n^H(X)$, where $\pi_n^H(X)$ refers to the stable homotopy group of $(G/H)_+\wedge X$.

If $K\subset H$, then the canonical map $p:G/K\to G/H$ induces the restriction map $Res_K^H$.
Conjugation should also be induced by the obvious map $C_g$ as $\pi_n^H(C_g)$ or something like that.

The transfer map seems to be the tricky one. A brief explanation is given in Peter May, p. 84, as follows:

For $H/K$, there is a transfer map $t(H/K):S^n\to (H/K)_+\wedge S^n$ constructed using the Pontrjagin-Thom map. I will take this as a fact. I am more intrigued about the map $t(p)$, defined a using the above $t(H/K)$ as follows:
$$
t(p):(G/H)_+\wedge S^n \cong G_+\wedge_H S^n \overset{t(H/K)}{\longrightarrow}  G_+\wedge_H(H/K)_+\wedge S^n \cong (G/K)_+\wedge S^n.
$$

My question is:

> Is the trasnfer $Tr^H_K$ obtained by pushing forward $t(\pi)$, that is, $Tr_K^H$ is the induced map
> $$
> t(\pi)_*:\{S^n,(G/H)_+\wedge X\}_G \longrightarrow \{S^n,(G/K)_+\wedge X\}_G ?
> $$

(If $X$ and $Y$ are finite $G$-CW complexes, I denote by $\{X,Y\}_G$ the colimit $\varinjlim_k [S^k\wedge X,S^k\wedge Y]_G$.)

Thank you.

PS: Notice the big effort I have made to avoid spectra.

Comment: Which book by Peter May do you mean? He has lots of writings on equivariant homotopy theory. There is already a lot hidden in here. The identification $\pi_n^G(G/H_+\wedge X)\cong \pi_n^H(X)$ is non-trivial and essentially equivalent to the Wirthmüller isomorphism, which is also constructed using a Pontryagin-Thom map. Also, the definition of $\{X,Y\}_G$ is wrong, you need to index over all $G$-representation (spheres), not just the trivial ones. But yes, this map should give the usual transfer, see for instance Schwede's lecture notes, Construction 4.15.

Comment: @VincentBoelens Sorry for the late response. It is a non-trivial matter and I wasn't able to reply before. The book I'm citing is _Equivariant homotopy and cohomology theory_. Regarding the definition of $\{X,Y\}$, I want to keep things as simple as possible. In my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4773346/the-mackey-functor-underline-pi-nx?rq=1) I tried to construct a Mackey functor $\underline{\pi}_n(X)$ which on objects $\underline{\pi}_n(X)(G/H)= \pi_n(X^H)$. As you pointed out, the transfer is a stable phenomenon. I have tried to encode that here in the...

Comment: ... simplest possible way. Finally, about the isomorphism $\pi_n^G((G/H)_+\wedge X)\cong \pi_n^H(X)$. I'm not familiar with the Wirthmüller isomorphism but I'm happy to accept as a fact that $[(G/H)_+\wedge S^n]_G\cong [S^n,(G/H)_+\wedge X]_G$. I hope this clarifies my choices when asking the question.  I should also say that Schwede's lectures notes are quite technical for me. I would appreciate an alternative reference or a detailed answer on this site, preferably using my language. Thank you again.